# Make CSS color with linear Gradients

Tags: css, colors, background-color, linear-gradients

I am new to CSS users, I really like this color. Is there anyone who knows how to make the background color like the picture that I point to blow?

I try to use linear gradients but did not get it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code

Generated From This Page https://cssgradient.io/

```css
.ht{
background: rgb(77,77,77);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(77,77,77,1) 0%, rgba(42,42,42,1) 100%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);width:500px;height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ht"><h1>Cool Background </h1></div>
```